# Minimization of function with two parameters.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Let this minimization,
$$
\min_{x\in[-2y,4y]}((1-(y+\frac{1}{2}x))^++(5/4-(y+\frac{1}{4}x))^++(7/4-(y-\frac{1}{4}x))^+)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$
with $y\geq 0$, $x\in\mathbb R$ and the notation $(.)^+$ means : 
$(z)^+=\max(0,z)$.

**Is there a solution of $(*)$** as in this example :

$$
\min_{x\in[-y/2,y]} [(-(y+2x))^++(-(y+x))^++(1-(y-x))^+]=(1-3/2y)^+
$$
Where the minimum is attained at $x = -y/2$.

I have tried by the mean of differentiation without success.

Is $x=-2y$ the solution of $(*)$ ? or it depends to $y$ ?

Comment: why don't you reformulate it as a linear optimization problem and see if you can find a solution to the KKT conditions?

Comment: @LinAlg I am not familiar with the KKT conditions and linear optimization ...

Comment: then just create a few plots for different values of $y$ and see if you can detect a pattern :)

Comment: What the notation $(\cdot ) ^+$ means?

Comment: @Cesareo $(z)^+=z$ if $z>0$ and $(z)^+=0$ if $z\leq 0$ in other words : $(z)^+=z\mathbb I_{z>0}$

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be arranged as a LP program

$$
\min_{x,y,z_1,z_2,z_3} z_1+z_2+z_3 \;\;\mbox{s. t.}
$$
$$
z_1=1-y-\frac x2\\
z_2=\frac 54-y-\frac x4\\
z_3=\frac 74-y+\frac x4\\
z_1 \ge 0\\
z_2 \ge 0\\
z_3 \ge 0\\
-2y \le x\\
x\le 4y\\
y \ge 0
$$

with one solution at

$$
x = -1, y = \frac 32, z_1 = 0, z_2 = 0, z_3 = 0
$$

Attached a plot showing in black the level surfaces for $f(x,y) = \max( 0,z_1)+\max(0,z_2)+\max(0,z_3)\;$ in red the lines $z_1=0, z_2=0, z_3=0$

[image]

Comment: Your post is interesting but could we obtain a solution (for the min) on $x\in[-2y,4y]$ for any $y>0$ not a single point (x,y) but something more general ? for instance $y<\alpha$ then $x=\beta y$ and $y\geq \alpha$ then $x=\gamma y$ (it is just an example like in my post I have provided another one). Do you understand my idea ? It is maybe the bold blue line what I am looking for ? it is something like $max(0,a+b.y)$ ?